# Can I show my private organs to a stranger on camera or live?

Tags: sex

Without marrying someone, is it a sin to display one's private parts to a stranger using camera or personally?

Comment: For what reason, medical checkup?

Comment: No for sex desire , if im 15 years old

Comment: `sex desire` if `15 years old` . why the **if** ? `sex desire` is always a `sex desire` and is haram to do anything out of it outside marriage, in any age

Answer (score 3):

In case you are a girl:

In Islam a girl will be religiously charged as it pass the 9 years in lunar calendar  which is 8 and 9 months aprox. in the solar calendar.

When a girl pass this it will be subjected to Islam Rules

> وَقُلْ لِلْمُؤْمِنَاتِ يَغْضُضْنَ مِنْ أَبْصَارِهِنَّ وَيَحْفَظْنَ
>   فُرُوجَهُنَّ وَلَا يُبْدِينَ زِينَتَهُنَّ إِلَّا مَا ظَهَرَ مِنْهَا ۖ
>   وَلْيَضْرِبْنَ بِخُمُرِهِنَّ عَلَىٰ جُيُوبِهِنَّ ۖ وَلَا يُبْدِينَ
>   زِينَتَهُنَّ إِلَّا لِبُعُولَتِهِنَّ أَوْ آبَائِهِنَّ أَوْ آبَاءِ
>   بُعُولَتِهِنَّ أَوْ أَبْنَائِهِنَّ أَوْ أَبْنَاءِ بُعُولَتِهِنَّ أَوْ
>   إِخْوَانِهِنَّ أَوْ بَنِي إِخْوَانِهِنَّ أَوْ بَنِي أَخَوَاتِهِنَّ
>   أَوْ نِسَائِهِنَّ أَوْ مَا مَلَكَتْ أَيْمَانُهُنَّ أَوِ التَّابِعِينَ
>   غَيْرِ أُولِي الْإِرْبَةِ مِنَ الرِّجَالِ أَوِ الطِّفْلِ الَّذِينَ
>   لَمْ يَظْهَرُوا عَلَىٰ عَوْرَاتِ النِّسَاءِ ۖ وَلَا يَضْرِبْنَ
>   بِأَرْجُلِهِنَّ لِيُعْلَمَ مَا يُخْفِينَ مِنْ زِينَتِهِنَّ ۚ وَتُوبُوا
>   إِلَى اللَّهِ جَمِيعًا أَيُّهَ الْمُؤْمِنُونَ لَعَلَّكُمْ تُفْلِحُونَ
>
> And tell the believing women to reduce [some] of their vision and
>   guard their private parts and not expose their adornment except that
>   which [necessarily] appears thereof and to wrap [a portion of] their
>   headcovers over their chests and not expose their adornment except to
>   their husbands, their fathers, their husbands' fathers, their sons,
>   their husbands' sons, their brothers, their brothers' sons, their
>   sisters' sons, their women, that which their right hands possess, or
>   those male attendants having no physical desire, or children who are
>   not yet aware of the private aspects of women. And let them not stamp
>   their feet to make known what they conceal of their adornment. And
>   turn to Allah in repentance, all of you, O believers, that you might
>   succeed.

[(24:31)](http://quran.com/24/31)

So you are 15 then you are subjected to these rules and so you have to obey and never show any part of your body to any stranger

In case you are a boy:

There are three ways that indicate whether a boy is charged:

1. Having hair on the private organ or underarms
2. Dreaming which means to dream with emission of semen
3. If none of above happens then you should wait to be 15 years in lunar calendar.

After that you have to pe subjected to this Aya:

> قُلْ لِلْمُؤْمِنِينَ يَغُضُّوا مِنْ أَبْصَارِهِمْ وَيَحْفَظُوا
>   فُرُوجَهُمْ ۚ ذَٰلِكَ أَزْكَىٰ لَهُمْ ۗ إِنَّ اللَّهَ خَبِيرٌ بِمَا
>   يَصْنَعُونَ
>
> Tell the believing men to reduce [some] of their vision and guard
>   their private parts. That is purer for them. Indeed, Allah is
>   Acquainted with what they do.

[(24:30)](http://quran.com/24/30)

So you are now subjected to Islam rules and you have not to do such things.

Answer (score 2):

It is in human nature that he hides his private part from public. Allah has made this natural instinct, a religious obligation too. Quran mentions that in [Surah 23, verse 5 and 6](http://quran.com/23/5-6)

> And they who guard their private parts. Except from their wives or those their right hands possess, for indeed, they will not be blamed -

Answer (score 2):

> قُل لِّلْمُؤْمِنِينَ يَغُضُّوا مِنْ أَبْصَارِهِمْ وَيَحْفَظُوا فُرُوجَهُمْ ذَلِكَ أَزْكَى لَهُمْ إِنَّ اللَّهَ خَبِيرٌ بِمَا يَصْنَعُونَ وَقُل لِّلْمُؤْمِنَاتِ يَغْضُضْنَ مِنْ أَبْصَارِهِنَّ….

“(O’ Prophet!) Say to the believing men that they cast down their looks and guard their private parts - that is purer for them; surely Allah is aware of what they do. And say to the believing women that they cast down their looks…”

Al-Qur’an · Surah al-Nur · Ayat 30-31

In this verse, it is stated they we are to guard our private parts. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not show even your head hair. In front of non-mahram you should wear Hijab.

Comment: If you could provide reference that would be even better.

Answer (score -3):

Without appealing to Quran or Hadith, I would simply say, would you feel comfortable if your own child would expose himself to someone else like this. That answer is obviously no, unless of course you are an adherent of a nudist movement.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Please go through [answer].